# Is there a parser for Java numeric string literals that returns the requested Number sub-class?

Tags: java, string, parsing, numbers

Within Java code it is possible to have numeric literals that use a suffix to indicate the type of the literal, e.g. `1D`, `0.15F` or `5L` for a `double`, `float` and `long` respectively. There is also support for hexadecimal and octal representations and possibly a few other things that I have not mentioned.

I'd like something equivalent to the parser that is used by `javac` internally that would return `Number` objects.

[`NumberFormat.parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29), as implemented in [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) only seems to produce `Double` and `Long` objects, with quite a few issues when some of the notations mentioned above are used.

Is there a parser in the standard class library of, say, Java 6 and onwards that is able to transparently parse such strings and return the proper sub-class of `Number`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not. You will have to write this method yourself. It would be simple enough, look at the last non-whitespace character and enter a switch block to return the proper Number subclass.

Comment: I have already done that, but it's a partial solution. Then I'd need to check the first character for octal and hexadecimal literals. Not to mention that generating the actual objects requires using `substring()` to remove the markers because most constructors choke on them... I fear that I'd come close to the complexity of writing the actual parser...

Comment: That's not sufficient.  You also need to look for the presence of `.` and `e` or `E` since `1e0` and `.0` are both `double`.  `double` vs `int` is important even when there is no fraction since `double` has a distinct `-0.0` while `(int) -0` is indistinguishable from `(int) 0`.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: I have already delved into the opposite operation (`toString()`), so I am aware of most pitfalls. This is why I am hoping for an existing class - writing and testing such a parser myself would not be trivial.

Comment: I'll accept this answer... It's not what I had hoped for, but it seems to be valid, at least within the scope of the standard Java classes.